# Redirect to a collection other than DefaultCollection

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-server-2019, azure-devops-server

There are 4 collections on my Server 2019. 
Each time, when I using URL http://tfsserver:8080/tfs/ to access TFS, I am redirected to http://tfsserver:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection.

Is there a way to redirect me to http://tfsserver:8080/tfs/MyCollection1? Because MyCollection1 is the one we always work on.

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let us know if you would like further assistance.

Answer (score 2):

> Redirect to a collection other than DefaultCollection

I used to have the same troubles as you. AFAIK, there is no such option to change/redirect the DefaultCollection.

Besides, after a period of research, I found that if I create a new Organization in one browser (like Google Chrome), whenever I log into Azure DevOps or access https://dev.azure.com, it always redirects me to https://dev.azure.com/NewOrg instead of https://dev.azure.com/DefaultOrg. However, when I access it in other browser (like Microsoft Edge), it still redirects the DefaultOrg.

So, I speculate this problem should not from Azure Devops but by browser. Then, to resolve this issue, I switch to the DefaultCollection, sign out current account, then re-sign in to the Azure Devops. It will redirects to the DefaultCollection.

When I log into Azure DevOps or access https://dev.azure.com next time, it redirects to the DefaultCollection. It works on my side, you can check if it works for you.

Hope this helps.